# Making crawler which crawls peoples from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

A person have an account on facebook in which he gives details in profile e.g his birthday city ,institute,age etc i want to search students frm FACEBOOK using Facebook API(on my own website asp.net) who study in University(BIIT) e.g if i type name Waleed in search box then all waleed should be shown in a listbox who study in Uni(BIIT) means institute name should be same for all waleed .

Comment: Just log in log out with facebook on my website

Answer (score 1):

Scraping/crawling is not allowed on facebook. You can only get data of users who authorized your App with the Graph API.

Scraping terms: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php